# Is it possible to change resolution from 1360x768 to 1366x768 without installing gpu driver

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, resolution

for some reason I disabled the gpu but i want the 1366x768 resolution back as it was when gpu enabled, is it possible to make custom resolution or by using some softwares etc. If yes, how?

Comment: How is a column six pixels wide (or 3 pixels on each side) going to improve the screen image?

Comment: @sawdust display is showing little blur text or image after every few inches

Comment: That would be because the SW is not configured to use the native resolution of the display.  You could improve your question by mentioning what laptop you have, and a screen-shot of Device Manager indicating the GPUs and video adapters available.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is built to be run on multiple hardware configurations. Therefore there are just basic drivers for graphic cards because it would take to much space to contain all relevant drivers. To switch resolutions that are different from the "standard" you will have to install the drivers from your graphics card's manufacturer.

Comment: Will resolution work without enabling the gpu, after installing drivers

Comment: @BlackFire What do you mean with "enabling the GPU"? If your GPU would not be enabled you wouldn't see anything on your monitor. Or do you have a laptop with On-CPU-GPU (Like newer Core-i Series) AND a dedicated GPU?

Comment: laptop have a dedicated nvidia gpu which i disabled and in DirectX Diagnostic Tool it is showing Microsoft Basic Display Adapter, Chip : Nvidia.

Comment: So **if** you have an OnBoard-GPU then you may want to install its own drivers. Each graphic "card" has its own drivers and if there is a legit reason for disabling the dedicated GPU you have to install the drivers for the other card. But this won't guarantee that you get your old resolution back. Only safe way to achieve that is to re-enable the dedicated GPU and install its drivers.

Comment: I need to run laptop without any graphics card enabled and is there any unsafe way you know it will be ok for me.

Comment: @iLLogical he has another question about disabling the GPU, which I answered, explaining how it probably would end badly unless there were integrated graphics as well. It seems does not have integrated graphics and disabled the driver for the discrete, so Windows is using the basic driver.